# #1005 - Can't create table `plbase`.`post_likes` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Tags: mysql

i tried  run the this

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;


# Dump of table followers
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `followers`;

CREATE TABLE `followers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `follower_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



# Dump of table login_tokens
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `login_tokens`;

CREATE TABLE `login_tokens` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `token` (`token`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `login_tokens_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



# Dump of table password_tokens
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `password_tokens`;

CREATE TABLE `password_tokens` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `token` (`token`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



# Dump of table post_likes
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `post_likes`;

CREATE TABLE `post_likes` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `post_likes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `post_likes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



# Dump of table posts
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts`;

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` varchar(160) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `posted_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



# Dump of table users
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` text,
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;




/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

And i got this error
SQL query: Copy

```sql
CREATE TABLE `post_likes` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `post_likes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `post_likes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
> #1005 - Can't create table `plbase`.`post_likes` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

I would be very thankful if someone could give me an idea here. I have been googling for solutions for a while now but could not find anything on this related to FOREIGN KEY. Thank you!

Comment: I removed the [tag:sql-server] tag.  MySQL <> SQL Server.

Comment: please explain more please

Comment: You tagged this question with `mysql` and with `sql-server`.  I removed the `sql-server` tag because they are not the same product.

Comment: ok thanks 
can you answer the question??